# Is there a way to access debug symbols at run time?

Tags: c, runtime, debug-symbols

Here's some example code to give an idea of what I want.

```
int regular_function(void)
{
     int x,y,z;
     /** do some stuff **/
     my_api_call();
     return x;
}
...
void my_api_call(void)
{
    char* caller = get_caller_file();
    int line = get_caller_line();
    printf("I was called from %s:%d\n", caller, line);
}
```

Is there a way to implement the `get_caller_file()` and `get_caller_line()`?  I've seen/used tricks like `#define`ing `my_api_call` as a function call passing in the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros.  I was wondering if there was a way to access that information (assuming it's present) at run time instead of compile time?  Wouldn't something like Valgrind have to do something like this in order to get the information it returns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have compiled your binary with debug symbols, you may access it using special libraries, like [libdwarf](http://reality.sgiweb.org/davea/dwarf.html) for DWARF debug format.

Comment: +1. If I didn't see it, this was half what I'd answer. The other half is for Windows executables you'd want to look into using DbgHelp.lib (aka DebugHelp). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679309(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is highly environment-specific.  In most Windows and Linux implementations where debug symbols are provided, the tool vendor provides or documents a way of doing that.  For a better answer, provide implementation specifics.

Comment: I was thinking generally, but would probably only ever do it on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging symbols, if available, need to be stored somewhere so the debugger can get at them. They may or may not be stored in the executable file itself.

You may or may not know the executable file name (`argv[0]` is not required to have the full path of the program name, or indeed have *any* useful information in it - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050961/is-argv0-name-of-executable-an-accepted-standard-or-just-a-common-conventio/2051031#2051031) for details).

Even if you could locate the debugging symbols, you would have to decode them to try and figure out where you were called from.

And your code may be optimised to the point where the information is useless.

That's the long answer. The short answer is that you should probably rely on passing in `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` as you have been. It's far more portable an reliable.