# not enough variables to fit a sentinel

Tags: c, gcc, function, exec, system-calls

According to [exec reference](http://www.linuxonly.nl/docs/2/2_Sentinel_warning_missing_sentinel_in_function_call.html), calls to exec (or stack checking vararg functions in general) requires a `(char*)NULL` aka 0 at the end of the parameter list. GCC, however, is complaining about the following code

```
char cmdFullPath[4096]; //yes this 4096 thing is bad coding practice 
...
execl(cmdFullPath, (char*)NULL);

//warning: not enough variable arguments to fit a sentinel
```

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050961/is-argv0-name-of-executable-an-accepted-standard-or-just-a-common-conventio

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That reference says that the prototype is

```
execl(const char * path, const char * arg, ...)
```

I read that as 2 parameters + (char*)NULL

something like :

```
execl(cmdFullPath, (const char*)NULL, (char*)NULL);
```

from the page:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", (char *)NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're right. Temporarily forgot that the 1st arg is mandatory (executable name). Doh!

Comment: what if the arg list is like arg1=val1, arg2=val2, arg3=val3, etc... or arg1 val1 arg2 val2 arg3 val3,etc ... ?

Comment: if i'm correct `return 0;` is never executed .. is it a convention to write it?

Comment: @philx_x - see here https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/693038/why-do-we-have-to-use-return - it's needed in C but optional in C++

Comment: @PreetSangha this is addressing a different question. My concern is that anything after `execl` is unnecessary because at that point the process's program text is literally overwritten with the one of `ls`.

Comment: @philx_x - please feel free to edit the question to improve!

Answer (score 2):

Its usual to pass the executable name in as the first parameter

So if the executable you are executing is "/bin/ls" (as per the link you posted) then the first parameter is "ls" and you'd THEN pass (char*)NULL in as the last (ie in this case 3rd) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass at least three arguments. The second one is argv[0] so it cannot be null.

```
execl(cmdFullPath, "", NULL)
```