# How to get program path

Tags: c++, gtk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to find the location of the executable in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933850/how-to-find-the-location-of-the-executable-in-c)

I'm writting an multi-platform app in C++ using GTK+ and I have a problem. I must get program path. E.g., when program is in `/home/user/program` (or `C:\Users\user\program.exe`), i have `/home/user/` (or `C:\Users\user\`).

Can and how I can do this?

Comment: Do you need an *absolute* or *relative* path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`argv[0]` contains the program name with path. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Probably not, unless you're having a problem with the contents of `argv[0]`.

Comment: You should't trust `argv[0]` - see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050961/is-argv0-name-of-executable-an-accepted-standard-or-just-a-common-conventi)

Answer (score 9):

For Win32/MFC c++ programs:

```
char myPath[_MAX_PATH+1];
GetModuleFileName(NULL,myPath,_MAX_PATH);
```

Also observe the remarks at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx,

In essence: WinMain does not include the program name in lpCmdLine, main(), wmain() and _tmain() should have it at argv[0], but:

> Note: The name of the executable in the command line that the
>   operating system provides to a process is not necessarily identical to
>   that in the command line that the calling process gives to the
>   CreateProcess function. The operating system may prepend a fully
>   qualified path to an executable name that is provided without a fully
>   qualified path.

Comment: Lol, I asked this question over 1 year ago... I don't need this answer now, sorry :)

Comment: Ok, but maybe someone else might find it useful ;)

Answer (score 3):

On windows..

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* defines FILENAME_MAX */
#ifdef WINDOWS
    #include <direct.h>
    #define GetCurrentDir _getcwd
#else
    #include <unistd.h>
    #define GetCurrentDir getcwd
 #endif

 char cCurrentPath[FILENAME_MAX];

 if (!GetCurrentDir(cCurrentPath, sizeof(cCurrentPath)))
     {
     return errno;
     }

cCurrentPath[sizeof(cCurrentPath) - 1] = '/0'; /* not really required */

printf ("The current working directory is %s", cCurrentPath);
```

Linux

```
char szTmp[32];
sprintf(szTmp, "/proc/%d/exe", getpid());
int bytes = MIN(readlink(szTmp, pBuf, len), len - 1);
if(bytes >= 0)
        pBuf[bytes] = '\0';
return bytes;
```

And you should look at this question..

[How do I get the directory that a program is running from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143174/c-c-how-to-obtain-the-full-path-of-current-directory)

Comment: Is not there a universal solution? :)

Comment: why downvote? the solution is a very interesting alternative IMO, especially if the main is not in your hands, e.g. if you are writing a library. +1

Comment: This anwser is incorrect; you are supplying the current working directory, which is totally different from the application path...
<edit>In the thread you linked, there is the same confusion</edit>

Comment: @OliverZendel, this answer is half correct. In windows, it's wrong, and your answer is correct. On linux it is perfectly correct. `readlink` of `/proc/pid/exe` does the same as `GetModuleFileName` in windows. Either way, the accepted answer is completely wrong.