# C- Using exec() in windows

Tags: c, windows, cygwin, exec

I've seen many many results for unix systems. I am using cygwin so I am using `unistd.h` library. I am trying to run this command but It does not run. What could I be missing here?

`execl("C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\CMD.EXE", "/c echo foo>C:\\Users\\Sarp\\Desktop\\foo.txt");`

Comment: You may want to escape the latter backslashes again: `C:\\\\Users\\\\Sarp\\\\Desktop\\\\foo.txt`.  But keep in mind that forward slashes work fine on Windows too, even natively (i.e. without the Cygwin abstraction layer).

Comment: What's the return value? Section 1.6.4 of this page (http://seit.unsw.adfa.edu.au/staff/sites/hrp/webDesignHelp/cygwin-ug-net-nochunks.html) appears to indicate that case sensitivity is not the issue.

Comment: @C2H5OH still, it doesn't change anything...

Comment: @enhzflep it returns -1

Comment: @SarpKaya - well, to quote a man page for execl (http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_execl.htm) 
RETURN VALUE

If any of the exec functions returns, an error will have occurred. The return value is -1, and the global variable errno will be set to indicate the error.

Comment: I changed it into `execl("C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\CMD.EXE", "/c echo foo>C:\\\\Users\\\\Sarp\\\\Desktop\\\\foo.txt",(char *)NULL);`

Now I get the output of `Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.` but it does not run anything...

Comment: I guess the problem here is not being able to pass parameters... But how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`execl` function call](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl) does **not** split the arguments for you.  This basically means that you need to separate each command line argument as a different string parameter when invoking the function.  For example:

```
execl("C::\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\CMD.EXE", "cmd.exe", "/c", 
      "echo", "foo", ">C:\\Users\\Sarp\\Desktop\\foo.txt")
```

However, I'm under the impression that the output redirection may not work (depending on how the Windows shell interprets those), so I encourage you to try [the `system()` function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) which resembles your usage case more closely.

Comment: Thanks for that but instead of `"cmd.exe"` if i just put `""` it still works, so really what should be written into the second argument as it has no effect to the actual parameters whatsoever?

Comment: The second parameter of `execl()` will become [the `argv[0]` string in the case of C programs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050961/is-argv0-name-of-executable-an-accepted-standard-or-just-a-common-conventi).

Comment: Note that in Windows the new process is passed a single argument string, so execl just appends the strings together.  (That's why the details of how the output redirection should be split into tokens doesn't matter.)

Comment: you can use shlex's shell split here! https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html