# segmentation fault in c program that counts characters

Tags: c, character, counting

I am new to C and trying to write a program that counts brackets, braces, spaces and new lines. The compiler issues the error: Error opening fileSegmentation fault (core dumped)

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    FILE *fp;
    char c;
    int blank, tab, openbrace, closedbrace,openbracket,closedbracket, newline=0;


if ((fp = fopen("argv[0]", "r")) == NULL)
   {
     fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file");
    }
 while ((c=fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
 {
switch(c)
    {

        case '{':
        openbrace++;

        case '}':
        closedbrace++;

        case '[':
        openbracket++;

        case ']':
        closedbracket++;

        case '\n':
        newline++;


     }
   }
fclose(fp);
printf("\nThe number of { are %d", openbrace);
printf("\nThe number of } are %d", closedbrace);
printf("\nThe number of [ are %d", openbracket);
printf("\nThe number of ] are %d", closedbracket);
printf("\nThe number of new lines are %d", newline);
}
```

Comment: `if( (fp = fopen( argv[1], "r" )) == NULL ) { perror(argv[1]) ... ` Error messages that do not contain the pathname and the reason for the error are useless and frustrating.

Comment: You want break statements after those case statements too.

Comment: Initialize all your counter variables to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
if ((fp = fopen(argv[0], "r")) == NULL)
```

`argv[0]` is the name of the program what you want is `argv[1]` which is the first user string.

So it should be this:

```
if ((fp = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

1) Exit immediately after the error case - don't keep going.

2) Open the argv[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050961/is-argv0-name-of-executable-an-accepted-standard-or-just-a-common-conventi), not "argv[0]" (argv[0] holds the [executable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050961/is-argv0-name-of-executable-an-accepted-standard-or-just-a-common-conventi), and you were enclosing it in a string)

```
fopen(argv[1], "r")
```

It is probably a good idea to make sure `argv[1]` exists by checking `argc` too.

Answer (score 0):

you need to exit the program when you print out the error. Instead, you go into the `while` loop anyway. and since `fp` is `null`, it crashes.