# Passing argument with *list doesn't work with execl

Tags: python, python-2.7, argv, os.execl

I have a python script which acts as launcher for other scripts. The script launches scripts from input arguments, following is some relevant code:

```
try:
    if verbose:
       print("Calling script ", args.script, " with arguments", *args.script_argument)
    os.execl(args.script, *args.script_argument)
except OSError as e:
    print("OSError: [Errno {0}] {1}: {2}".format(e.errno, e.strerror, args.script), file=sys.stderr)
```

`args` is an object returned by `parse_args()` from `ArgumentParser`. `args.script_arguments` is retrieved with `nargs=argparse.REMAINDER`.

This is the script the launcher is calling:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sys.argv)
```

From the print before the `os.execl` call, I can see that the argument is properly set, however the script prints an argument less.

For example, if call the launcher with `./launcher.py -v script foo bar`

The launcher will print, `Calling script script with arguments foo bar`.

However, the script prints `['script.py', 'bar']`. Why isn't `foo` printed from the script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument you pass to `os.execl` (after the `script` argument) is the "name" of the program being run (it can be anything, doesn't have to be the actual path to the executable file). That's what `script.py` would see as its `sys.argv[0]` (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv), and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050961/is-argv0-name-of-executable-an-accepted-standard-or-just-a-common-conventi), for example, explaining how `argv[0]` works).

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv):

> argv[0] is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a full pathname or not)

To get the behavior you expect, call it like:

```
os.execl(args.script, args.script, *args.script_argument)
```

Comment: Indeed, this is the solution. However, there's something that's still unclear to me. If the first argument of `execl` is the name of the script and the second is the path, calling it with `execl(script, *args)` where args is a list, should have used the first element of the list as the path to the script, isn't it?

Comment: The first is the path, the second is the name.