# C program, that prints its executable file name

Tags: c++, c

Suppose source code file name is `test.cpp`. When it is compiled, it produce `test.exe` file. When I execute it, it should identify its file name that is `test.exe` and print it.

I'm able to get list of all the files and directories present in the current directory using following code:

```
DIR * directory;
struct dirent * direct;
direct = readdir(directory);
```

But, how can I identify the associated file name, in this case which is `"test.exe"`?

Comment: Why does your C source have a C++ source file extension? The two languages are *not* the same, you realize this?

Comment: The current directory isn't necessarily where the executable is. On most occasions, it isn't anywhere near it.

Comment: @Amadeus That is not a duplicate, because it is about a Windows-specific solution. The OP here seems to be looking for a standard solution

Comment: Re-opened, because it wasn't a duplicate. I'm quite certain duplicates exist, but it should be a correct one.

Comment: Heh ..you know, I suppose my eyes stopped when I saw "text.exe" and assumed it was for windows/DOS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.exe)  ...but, you're right, he uses readdir() which is indicative of something other than windows.

Comment: Not possible in general. The program might not have any filename when executing (weird, but possible at least on Linux).

Comment: I'm surprise this hasn't been referred to yet:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023306/finding-current-executables-path-without-proc-self-exe  That's close enough that this could have probably been closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You know the name of the executable when you're building it; the
simplest solution is to embed it in the program, using a `-D` or `/D`
option to define a macro on the command line.

Other than that, the generic answer is that it isn't possible:

> ## According to the standard
>
> - `argv[0]` should contain the name which was used to invoke the
>     program (whatever that means).  Which is nice, but 1) it isn't even
>     implementable under Unix, and 2) under most systems, there are all sorts
>     of aliasing which means that the name used to invoke the program bears
>     no relationship to the name of the executable.
>
> ## Under Windows
>
> - There's a system function `GetModuleFileName` which can be used to
>     obtain the *path* of the executable.  Once you've got the path, the last
>     element of the path is the name of your executable.
>
> ## Under Unix
>
> - It's fundamentally impossible.  When starting a new process, Unix
>     takes separate arguments for the path to the executable and for what
>     ends up in `argv[0]`, so they can potentially have no relationship to
>     one another.  It all depends on who starts your process.  `bash` will
>     put the full path to the executable in the environment variable `"_"`,
>     so you can use `getenv` to get it.  But that only works if your program
>     was started by `bash`.  On most Unices, you can also find it in the
>     `/proc` filesystem, if you know your way around there; but the
>     organization of this varies from one Unix to the next.  Note too that
>     because of hard links, you're executable may not have just one
>     name.

The real question is why you want to do this.  What is the problem you
are trying to solve?

Comment: Do you have a crystal ball? I would never guess that this was what OP need. It was clearly a runtime question for me.

Comment: @JonatanGoebel The OP asked how to obtain the name of the executable.  He may have been thinking run time, but the name is generally known to the build process, and so can be determined at build time.  (The OP didn't specify what he was trying to accomplish, so it's hard to say whether this solution would solve the problem or not---I actually have my doubts that it would, since I can't think of a problem that would require this knowledge.  But it's what he asked for.)

Answer (score 18):

In your main function, `argv[0]` is the name of the executable from the command line

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    printf("%s", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/OCwt3f)

This prints the command name, which is the directory relative to the current working directory, plus the executable name (if available, which is not guaranteed)
To get the current working directory, use `getcwd()` standard library C function.

Extracting the file name from the command path in `argv[0]` is platform specific : unix use slashes '`/`', windows allows mixed uses of slash `/` and backslash `\`, and any other platform could use any other path separator. Extracting the file name from a path requires a cross-platform library, such as *Qt or Boost*. On **POSIX environments**, basename could be used.

Comment: argv[0] is your command, not necessarily the name of the executable

Comment: @JonatanGoebel : true, in case of symbolic links (do you see other cases where it could be different?)

Comment: @galinette See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050961/is-argv0-name-of-executable-an-accepted-standard-or-just-a-common-conventi

Comment: @galinette, if OP wants only the filename, it is also necessary to call `basename` to remove the path.

Comment: `argv[0]` can be absolutely anything. Shells pass the command as entered by the user as `argv[0]`. It may or may not be related to the filename, depending on the shell. In general, programs that run other programs are free to pass anything they want as `argv`.

Comment: @n.m. You're right in practice, but the standard says that `argv[0]` should be the name used to invoke the program.  (Which strictly speaking isn't implementable under Unix.  When I invoke one of the `exec` functions, I can set `argv[0]` to whatever I want.)

Comment: **getcwd()** is not standard **C** library its for Linux systems only.

Answer (score 13):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that your program can be launched as:

```
/home/user/./app
```

In this case you can get the name by using `strrchr`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *appname;

    appname = strrchr(argv[0], '/'); /* '\\' on Windows */
    printf("%s\n", appname ? ++appname : argv[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: have you heard about `basename`?

Comment: basename is posix, not stdlib, isn't it?

Comment: @galinette, yes, is part of POSIX

Comment: Won't work under Windows, which has backslashes. Actually, since paths is a platform specific question, it cannot be answered simply without a platform abstraction library such as Qt (Boost?)

Comment: @Alter Mann : he has .exe extension, which other platform than Windows use it ??

Comment: @AlterMann : why are you saying it finds the last occurence of the string? As backslash is the C escaping character, it needs to be escaped.

Comment: @AlterMann regarding dirent : he may be using CygWin (POSIX) or this with MSVC : http://www.two-sdg.demon.co.uk/curbralan/code/dirent/dirent.html

Answer (score 4):

### On Linux specifically:

you might use [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) and the `/proc/self/exe` symlink, so use [readlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html) on that. Once you did that, you could use [basename(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/basename.3.html) or [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) on the obtained symlink.

However, be aware that a program might not always have a file path. It could have *several* file paths (for example `/bin/rbash` is a symlink to `/bin/bash`, and the shell process behave differently when invoked as `rbash` or as `bash`). Sometimes a given file (actually an [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode), see [inode(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html)) has *several* hardlinks to it. In weird cases there is none. 
And it could happen that a program is [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)-ed and then removed with [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) (perhaps from another process scheduled to run before yours) etc..

<sup>(BTW, your question is OS specific; [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) is POSIX and there are some operating systems not even having directories, and `readdir` is not mentioned by the [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)) standard; check by reading [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf))</sup>

I experimented with the following (pathological) `./selfremove` program (in my `/home/basile/tmp/` directory) which removes its own binary:

```
 // file selfremove.c
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int
 main (int argc, char **argv)
 {
   char selfpath[128];
   memset (selfpath, 0, sizeof (selfpath));
   if (readlink ("/proc/self/exe", selfpath, sizeof (selfpath) - 1) < 0)
     {
       perror ("first readlink");
       exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
     };
   printf ("initial /proc/self/exe -> %s\n", selfpath);
   if (unlink (argv[0]))
     {
       fprintf (stderr, "unlink %s: %m\n", argv[0]);
       exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
     };
   printf ("%s unlinked\n", argv[0]);
   if (readlink ("/proc/self/exe", selfpath, sizeof (selfpath) - 1) < 0)
     {
       perror ("second readlink");
       exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
     };
   printf ("final /proc/self/exe -> %s\n", selfpath);
   return 0;
 }
```

It works, and the kernel is constructing a `* (deleted)` symlink (since a perverse coder might rename an executable as `selfremove (deleted)`, so that kernel added suffix is only an indication ....):

```
 % ./selfremove 
 initial /proc/self/exe -> /home/basile/tmp/selfremove
 ./selfremove unlinked
 final /proc/self/exe -> /home/basile/tmp/selfremove (deleted)
```

So even with `/proc/self/exe` you cannot always trust the result.

If you assume that your program has been [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)-ed by some shell (or similar program doing [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html)) -and that is not *always* the case- then the [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) might have been used (and searched from your `main`'s `argv[0]`  if it has no `/`). You might use [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) as `getenv("PATH")` to get it from your environment (see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) for more). That `$PATH` is generally set and used, but they are pathological cases too.

So in general there is no way to reliably print its own executable (as my pathological `selfremove.c` demonstrates). In most cases you could find it (e.g. by `readlink` of `/proc/self/exe`, or by searching in `$PATH` using `argv[0]`).

Answer (score 3):

In Linux systems, I think you can also use [`basename(char *path);`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/basename) from [`libgen.h`](http://linux.die.net/include/libgen.h), 
try `$ man basename`:

> Print NAME with any leading directory components removed.  If specified, also remove a trailing SUFFIX.

I tried it as:

```
// filename.c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<libgen.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char* exe_name = basename(argv[0]);
    printf(" Executable Name: %s", exe_name);
    printf("\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Observations,compiled and tested it as:

```
taxspanner@:~$ ls filename.c
filename.c
taxspanner@:~$ gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -pedantic filename.c -o filename
taxspanner@:~$ ls filename*
filename  filename.c
taxspanner@:~$
```

Now run it in current directory:

```
taxspanner@:~$ ./filename 
 Executable Name: filename
```

Using absolute path:

```
taxspanner@:~$ pwd
/home/taxspanner
taxspanner@:~$ /home/taxspanner/filename 
 Executable Name: filename
```

Relative path:

```
taxspanner@:~$ cd study/divide-5/
taxspanner@:~/study/divide-5$ pwd
/home/taxspanner/study/divide-5
taxspanner@:~/study/divide-5$ ls ../../filename*
../../filename  ../../filename.c
taxspanner@:~/study/divide-5$ ../../filename
 Executable Name: filename
taxspanner@:~/study/divide-5$
```

one more try with executable name with suffix:

```
taxspanner@:~$ gcc -std=gnu99 -Wall -pedantic filename.c -o filename.out
taxspanner@:~$ ./filename.out 
 Executable Name: filename.out
taxspanner@:~$ cd study/divide-5/
taxspanner@:~/study/divide-5$ ../../filename.out 
 Executable Name: filename.out
```

[Be careful when using it](http://linux.die.net/man/3/basename): Both `dirname()` and `basename()` may modify the contents of path, so it may be desirable to *pass a copy* when calling one of these functions.

Give it a try!!

Comment: Nice explanation!  And I didn't know that a program in a relative path can be launched using `program*`

Comment: @AlterMann Sorry it was typo in my answer,  for relative path we don't need `*`, I just used `../../filename`