# checking process in linux without using top and ps command

Tags: linux

I want to view a status of a process among 2000 processes, Without using `top` and `ps` 
commands.

The name of the process is **tom**.

Comment: What is a "status process" ? Please **edit your question**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) don't have any name** (only the *program* it is running has one, but see also [pthread_setname_np(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getname_np.3.html)... you might have pathological cases like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47009791/841108)). It has a pid (which is some integer number, like 1234, of type  `pid_t`). See [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) and [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). Use [pidof(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pidof.1.html) and [pgrep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html) to find the pid of some process. An [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) program (e.g. `/bin/bash`)  can be run by several processes (or none, or only one).

You may use [kill(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html) with a zero signal number to check that the process exists.

Most importantly, you should consider using `/proc/`  (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more). For the process of pid 1234, see `/proc/1234/` which has several files and subdirectories (notably `/proc/1234/status` and `/proc/1234/maps`). Try `cat /proc/$$/status` and `cat /proc/$$/maps` and `stat /proc/$$/exe` and `ls -l /proc/$$/` in a terminal (then replace `$$` by whatever pid is interesting for you).

The `top` and `ps` utilities (and also `pidof`, `pgrep`, ...) are using that `/proc/` (which is the mean by which the Linux kernel shows information on processes, and on the system itself). And you can write your program (or script) doing that too and using `/proc/`. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12237783/841108).

From inside a program, you can explore `/proc/` like you would explore other file trees, e.g. using [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) etc.