# Linux - Kill process by path

Tags: linux, process, executable, kill

How can I kill a process by its executable's absolute file path? Hence, I want to kill all processes that were created from an executable at a given location?

**ANSWER:**

```
kill $(ps aux | grep '<absolute executable path>' | awk '{print $2}')
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510673/find-and-kill-a-process-in-one-line-using-bash-and-regex

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. Updated my question with the answer.

Answer (score 4):

**ANSWER:**

```
kill $(pgrep -f /absolute/executable/path)
```

Answer (score 3):

```sh
function killpath {
    ps aux |  awk '{print $2"\t"$11}' | grep -E '^\d+\t'"$1"'$' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -SIGTERM
}
```

Usage:

```sh
killpath /Applications/Waterfox.app/Contents/MacOS/waterfox
```

What it does:

- `ps aux`: List processes
- `awk '{print $2"\t"$11}'`: get column `2` (PID) and `11` (Executable) and separate them by a `\t` tab character
- `grep -E '^\d+\t'"$1"'$'`: Match a regex

  - `^`: Beginning of line
  - `\d+`: one or more digits
  - `\t`: Tab character introduced previously
  - `"$1"` The input to the function, e.g. `/Applications/Waterfox.app/Contents/MacOS/waterfox`
  - `$`: End of line
- `awk '{print $1}'`: Get only the `1`st column, the Process ID.
- `xargs`: transform linebreaks to spaces

Here is how that looks on data:

```sh
# killpath /Applications/Waterfox.app/Contents/MacOS/waterfox

# ps aux
# USER           PID    %CPU %MEM  VSZ     RSS       TT  STAT STARTED   TIME     COMMAND
luckydonald      23265  04,6 10,3  9222008 1736020   ??  S    Sat10am   45:48.77 /Applications/Waterfox.app/Contents/MacOS/waterfox -foreground
luckydonald      23266  02,0 05,3  5743400  362344   ??  R    Sat10am   11:52.52 /Applications/Waterfox.app/Contents/MacOS/waterfox -foreground
luckydonald      42128  04,5 00,2  4337884   35608 s002  S+    1:17am    0:06.84 /usr/local/Cellar/docker-compose/1.23.2/libexec/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/docker-compose logs -f --tail 100 r2tg

# awk '{print $2"\t"$11}'
23265   /Applications/Waterfox.app/Contents/MacOS/waterfox
23266   /Applications/Waterfox.app/Contents/MacOS/waterfox
42128   /usr/local/Cellar/docker-compose/1.23.2/libexec/bin/python3.7

# 1="/Applications/Waterfox.app/Contents/MacOS/waterfox"
# grep -E '^\d+\t'"$1"'$'
23265   /Applications/Waterfox.app/Contents/MacOS/waterfox
23266   /Applications/Waterfox.app/Contents/MacOS/waterfox

#  awk '{print $1}'
23265
23266

# xargs
23265 23266

# xargs kill -SIGTERM
kill -SIGTERM 23265 23266
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [pkill(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pkill.1.html) (or perhaps [killall(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/killall.1.html)...)

If you are coding a program you might consider using [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html). You would then [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) then loop on [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) the `/proc/` directory (use also [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) and don't forget the [closedir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/closedir.3.html)). There are pathological cases (a [self-removing program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47009791/841108)).

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot didn't find any solution that works.
I resolved my issue may it will work for you.

If there are multiple **applications with the same name but different locations** then first find out the process id by giving the complete path to it.
Suppose there are two applications running whose locations are:

1. /home/ubuntu/Sachin/printMsg
2. /home/ubuntu/Sachin/second/printMsg

(printMsg is the name of the application.) We want to close 1st one then we can write the following command:

```
kill $(pidof "/home/ubuntu/Sachin/printMsg")
```

Explanation:

Command `pidof "/home/ubuntu/Sachin/printMsg"` returns process id. and using that process id we can use the kill command to close the application.