# Getting the program's directory on Linux

Tags: c++, linux

I'm wondering how I can get the  directory of my program on Linux. For instance, if I have my program located under `/home/myproject/` and I get the directory, it should be `/home/myproject/` regardless of what directory I'm calling the program from. I need this functionality because I need to be able to access a configuration file located under the same folder as my program, regardless of where the program's folder is located.

I've tried using `getcwd()`, but here's what it does:

If I'm currently in the same folder as the program is, it will work. However, if I was in `/root` and tried executing the program which is located under `/home/myproject`, it would give me `/root`.

If I just do something like...

```
std::ifstream is("anotherfile");
```

It will work as long as I'm in the same directory, but it does the same as above when I'm not.

Comment: `readlink("/proc/self/exe")` - or use some library such as Qt which provides `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()` .

Comment: The UNIX way is to store the configuration file(s) in a known directory, independent of where the executable is located. Typically, the executable is installed somewhere by a root user, and is used by one or more normal users. These users may have their private configuration file, typically named .appname.conf and stored in a user's home directory. A default configuration file is often found in  the /etc directory.

Comment: Although I would agree with @BjornA. in general, there are use cases for getting the executable's directory.  One I've used is to provide an option to debug an executable from the build directory by placing a path config file in the same directory within the build tree, while not requiring a recompile to then install the executable and have the installed executable get resources from `/usr/share/<package>` or `/usr/local/share/<package>`.

Comment: @BjornA. Thanks, I'm aware that configuration files get stored in /etc/ but I never thought of putting the file there! I'll be using this solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Linux, you could use `/proc/`. Read carefully [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

I'm suggesting reading the symlink in `/proc/self/exe` using [readlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html). It gives your executable. You might use [dirname(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dirname.3.html) on it to get its directory. Be also aware of [realpath(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/closedir.3.html) which might be useful (actually not, since, as commented by Daniel Schepler, `/proc/self/exe` is a canonical path....).

This is Linux specific, and won't work in rare pathological cases (your executable being removed or renamed during execution). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47009791/841108).

Remember that Linux don't have *folders* (they are just a GUI artefact) but [*directories*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)). See also [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), [closedir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/closedir.3.html), [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html), [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html), etc....

At last, the Unix tradition is to keep user-specific configuration files under `$HOME` (often with hidden dotfile, e.g. `$HOME/.inputrc`) and system-wide configuration files under `/etc/`. You can get `$HOME` with [getenv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) as `getenv("HOME")`. See [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html). In pathological cases such a `getenv` could fail.

BTW, you could even adopt a convention of testing with `getenv` if some particular environment variable is set (e.g. `MYPROGCONFIG`) and if it is set, use that as your configuration file. Don't forget to *document* such conventions.

Comment: I thought `/proc/<pid>` and `/proc/self` symlinks already pointed to canonicalized pathnames, due to the kernel implementation being to look up the inode in a reverse name map, or something along those lines.