# How to delete .exe output file after program finishes work

Tags: c, linux

I use gcc-compiler at Ubuntu 18.04. To compile and run a program I use command:

```
gcc program.c -o program.exe && ./program.exe
```

So, how can I automatically delete this program.exe file after program finishes work?

Comment: `rm program.exe`?

Comment: `\rm program.exe` to avoid rm -i aliasing

Comment: yes, it works, ty. but what does it mean "-i aliasing"?

Comment: Not a [C] question, or even a programming question; it is a bash shell question.

Answer (score 2):

That should do the trick:

```
gcc program.c -o program.exe && ./program.exe && rm program.exe
```

Please nothing that usually binary programs in Linux doesn't have the `.exe` extension (but nothing prevents you from putting it, it's a just a little misleading).

Your `rm`  could be some shell [alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html). Then you could force the real `rm` program to run by giving its (standard) path `/bin/rm` (instead of just `rm` in the command line above).

Answer (score -1):

On Linux and Unix systems, an executable is allowed to *remove itself when running* (using [remove(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/remove.3.html) or [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html)). I gave an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47009791/841108). But this is *not common* practice (and could confuse your user).

So you might code your C program with an explicit `unlink` doing that. This is *unusual*, and you should document that you are doing so.

Most executables are somehow permanent and are expected to be reusable a lot of times. You need to document why you don't want such a common behavior (and explain precisely why, when and how should the executable be deleted).

And I recommend compiling your executable with all warnings and debug info, so with `gcc -Wall -g program.c -o program` (later you could ask for optimization by adding `-O2`). This would ease debugging.

Of course, if you just want to remove an executable *after* it finishes running completely, you can simply use [rm(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rm.1.html) (as explained by [blue112's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52207128/841108)). You should explain why (and when) you want to do so (running `rm program` just after execution of `./program` is unusual).

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP asks how to delete a program after it finishes its work, and I am explaining that such a program could delete itself (even if that is unusual).