# How to start a python program recursive with os.execv?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following lines:

```
#!/root/p34/bin/python 
import os
import sys

for i in range(10):
    print(i)

currentFile = os.path.abspath(__file__)
print(currentFile)  
os.execv(currentFile, sys.argv)
```

When I try to run from console(Ubuntu 14.04) ./restart.py I get:

```
': [Errno 2] No such file or directory'
```

When I run `/root/p34/bin/python restart.py` I get python error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "restart.py", line 10, in <module>
    os.execv(currentFile, sys.argv)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Why are you using `os.execv()` in the first place?

Comment: I want to start again the program... this is a hack to avoid lxml memory leak

Comment: Unfortunately,you cant.

Comment: @qqvc: sure you can, provided you pass in the correct values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.execv` does not look for shebang lines; that is a shell function instead.

Use [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.executable) to get the path to the current Python binary:

```
os.execv(sys.executable, [sys.executable] + sys.argv)
```

Comment: is it so that the `[sys.exectubale]` prepend is required because of the 'OS-level' 'argv replacement', so to speak?

Comment: @naxa: `os.execv` passes the arguments to the executable, and the first argument *must* be the name of the executable. Many UNIX tools rely on that to alter behaviour based on what symlink was used to execute the tool, for example.

Comment: @naxa: In other words, you can pass in any string you like, but not all programs will like having something weird passed in.

Comment: thanks! do you happen to have a historical hint on whether there was a time when programmers did not realize that they lack a way for the loaded program image to identify itself, and used exec*/argv differently? It seems like a convention and it's rather strange it's not structural! (I suspect C for popularizing the convention.)

Comment: @naxa: [Is "argv\[0\] = name-of-executable" an accepted standard or just a common convention?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2050961)