# C++ File Paths Issue

Tags: c++, directory, sdl, filepath

When I use this code to load an image for SDL to render:

```
SDL_Texture* testimg = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "testz.bmp");
```

(or)

```
SDL_Texture* testimg = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "/testz.bmp");
```

the image doesn't render at all. However... if I use this code:

```
SDL_Texture* testimg = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, "../bin/testz.bmp");
```

SDL draws the image just fine. "bin" is the folder the .exe is in. So how do I fix this file paths issue?

edit: another possibility may be that visual studio, for some reason, is running the exe it put in the bin folder in another location which doesnt have the image...

Comment: Did you try `"./testz.bmp"`?

Comment: Just tried it, it doesn't work.

Comment: Run your exe with the `bin` folder as working directory.

Comment: Try looking at the "current working directory" of your application. Development environments may place this slightly differently than a terminal would. You can find the current working firectory with `getcwd()`. You can explicitly change in in your code or you can check the development environments configuration (there will be an option to change it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the directory where your executable is installed is not the same thing as the current directory of the process that your operating system starts, when it runs this executable.

It's fairly obvious that the current directory of your started process is the sibling directory of its executable.

Comment: so what would i do to fix it?

Comment: @Omega As mentioned run your program from the correct working directory, or switch the working directory programmatically.

Comment: It may not be obvious how to specify the working directory in Visual Studio. Look through the Project Settings - it's probably in there somewhere.

Comment: i found where to specify the working directory, but i don't know how to set it to just be "wherever the exe is located"

Comment: There should be an environment variable that expands to the path you want.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might work is to use `argv[0]` to make sure the correct base path is used. Assuming you're using standard `main()`, it would go something like this:

```
std::string base_path;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    base_path = argv[0];
    size_t last_slash = base_path.find_last_of('/');
    if(last_slash == std::string::npos)
        base_path = ".";
    else base_path.erase(last_slash + 1);
    // Anything else you need to do in `main()`
    return 0;
}
```

And then your loading would look like this:

```
SDL_Texture* testimg = IMG_LoadTexture(renderer, base_path + "testz.bmp");
```

If it's in a different file than `main()`, you'll also need to redeclare `base_path` with `extern`:

```
extern std::string base_path;
```

And of course you need to `#include <string>` for this to work.

If all your loading is done in `main()`, you can make this a bit better by moving the declaration of `base_path` into `main()`:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::string base_path = argv[0];
    // The rest is the same
}
```

Comment: This is unreliable, because there are almost no guarantees about `argv[0]`. There is no guarantee that it has a path, and there's no guarantee that it's encoded in a way that can represent an arbitrary path (with Windows' convention of ANSI character encoding that would be a short name path, and AFAIK no compiler does that). For Windows one can use `GetModuleFileName(0)` to get the executable's path.

Comment: Perhaps. However, a technique similar to this (but using `boost::filesystem::path` instead of `std::string`) has worked just fine for me both on Mac (which I think should have guarantees about argv[0] due to POSIX? Not certain though) and on Windows.

Comment: POSIX gives no such guarantee, sorry. And neither does Windows. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2051047/464581 for some practical code. It's not perfect but it's in the right direction. Like very concrete hinting. ;-)

Comment: Even so, using `argv[0]` will work in most environments. Of course, the original poster could use that `GetModuleFileName(0)` in place of `argv[0]` if they're worried, like you suggested. And once you have the executable path, the rest of what I describe in this post would be the same.