# fscanf not scanning any numbers

Tags: c, scanf, format-specifiers

I am currently developing a simple C application. It takes a single file as a command line argument, which is formatted like:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
etc.
```

However, for whatever reason, `fscanf` never scans the numbers! Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    FILE *file = fopen(*argv, "r");
    int i1, i2, i3;
    while (fscanf(file, "%d,%d,%d", &i1, &i2, &i3) == 3) {
        printf("Doing stuff with %d, %d, and %d...\n", i1, i2, i3);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

If you run it with the filename as an argument, then it immediately exits, due to `fscanf` returning 0. I've tried several variations of this, to no avail. How do I make `fscanf` read the numbers correctly?

Comment: `fopen(*argv, "r")` --> `fopen(*++argv, "r")` or `fopen(argv[1], "r")`

Comment: Why don't you check the return value of `fopen()`?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY *facepalm* Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: @SouravGhosh For my purposes, the file can be assumed to exist.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Don't **assume**. Check and be sure. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh It's only for personal usage, anyway ;p

Comment: It is simply a misunderstanding. (it contains the command in C.) It is often the case.

Comment: @SouravGhosh While you have a general point -- for chrissake, always check return values! --, it wouldn't help here! The program can open `argv[0]` alright, alas it will only be able to scan three comma separated numbers from those bytes under exceptional circumstances ;-).

Comment: What happened to the answers?

Comment: You're opening the program executable file

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2050961/5399734

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superficial answer: wrong file was opened as code should have used `argv[1]` rather than `*argv`.

Let us look deeper.

Code had troubles and lacked error checking in at least 2 places.

1. `FILE *file = fopen(*argv, "r");` was not followed by a test on `file`.  This classic check would not have detected OP's problem as the file, the executable, was open-able.
2. The return value from `fscanf(file, "%d,%d,%d", &i1, &i2, &i3)` was only lightly tested.  Return values of `EOF 0 1  2 3` were possible yet only `EOF 3` were expected.  Had code tested for non-`EOF 3`, the problem would have rapidly been found.

Lesson to be learned:  Insure code, especially mis-behaving code, has adequate error checking.  Saves the coder time in the long run.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected argument count %d.\n", argc);
    return 1;
  } 
  FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (file == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file: \"%s\"", argv[1]);
    return 1;
  } 
  int i1, i2, i3;
  int n;
  while ((n = fscanf(file, "%d,%d,%d", &i1, &i2, &i3)) == 3) {
    printf("Doing stuff with %d, %d, and %d...\n", i1, i2, i3);
  }
  if (n != EOF) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected scan failure count %d\n", n);
    return 1;
  }
  fclose(file);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most of this was checked in earlier iterations. I checked the file (it wasn't `NULL`), I looked at the return values of `fscanf` (it kept returning `0`), and checking the values of the `in` (they never changed.)

Answer (score 2):

As noted by BLUEPIXY, you should use the second element of the `argv` array: `argv[1]`:

```
FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

The first element (`argv[0]` or `*argv`) is the name of the program being executed - it's not the right file to open.