# taking command line parameters in C?

Tags: c, command-line

So I'm pretty new to C and am trying to learn how to make it take command line inputs, I typed it in what I'm hoping is the correct syntax and I'm trying to get it so you type in 2 numbers and it returns those two numbers added together. The program does compile but when I try to run it, it takes the parameters and they're printed completely wrong, almost as if they're printing the memory addresses.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int addition(int a, int b);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc != 3) {
        printf("You must enter 2 numbers!");
        return TRUE;
    }
    else {
        int answer = addition((int)*(argv[0]), (int)*(argv[1]));
        printf("%d + %d = %d", argv[0], argv[1], answer);
        return FALSE;
    }
}

int addition(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

So what am I doing wrong? The output when I put in  2 3 is:

```
155 + 50 = 165
```

Comment: `argv[0]` points to the program name (when available); `argv[1]` points to the 1st argument; ...; `argv[argc]` is a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: BTW: in addition to the answer below, you want `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`. `argv[0]` is the name of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace these lines:

```
int answer = addition((int)*(argv[0]), (int)*(argv[1]));
printf("%d + %d = %d", argv[0], argv[1], answer);
```

with:

```
int answer = addition(atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]));
printf("%d + %d = %d", atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]), answer);
```

As said in another answer by David Hoelzer, the arguments contains null terminated byte strings. Using `atoi()` will convert the strings into integers.

Use `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` instead since they will actually be the ones that will contain the values you entered. As per the ISO C standard specification:

> If the value of argc is greater than zero, the string pointed to by argv[0] represents the program name; argv[0][0] shall be the null character if the program name is not available from the host environment.

`argv[0]` would contain the name of the program.

More information regarding `argv[0]` as the name of the program can be found in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050961/is-argv0-name-of-executable-an-accepted-standard-or-just-a-common-conventi).

With regards to the code, you could always store the arguments in a variable like this:

```
int a = atoi(argv[1]);
int b = atoi(argv[2]);
```

and then pass them to your `addition()` function and use it in the `printf()` part.

Answer (score 2):

The values that are being passed to you via the `**argv` are not integers, they are null terminated byte strings. In order to perform the addition, you would first need to use something like `atoi()` to convert them to integers. Otherwise you are performing numeric addition on character arrays.

Answer (score 1):

```
int answer = addition((int)*(argv[0]), (int)*(argv[1]));
printf("%d + %d = %d", argv[0], argv[1], answer);
```

I'm afraid this won't work as you expect. `argv[x]`s are pointers to chars, rather than integers. For example, if you in put "2 3", `argv[0]` points to a string representing the name of the running program(or a null pointer if the name isn't available), `argv[1]` points to "2", `argv[2]` points to "3", and `argv[argc]`(namely `argv[3]`) points to a null pointer.

To convert a string, which is essentially a const char array, simply casting doesn't work. You can call `atoi()` function instead. Here is the code that works (without error handling):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int addition(int a, int b);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if(argc != 3) {
        printf("You must enter 2 numbers!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    else {
        int a = atoi(argv[1]), b = atoi(argv[2]);
        int answer = addition(a, b);
        printf("%d + %d = %d", a, b, answer);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}

int addition(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

When inputing "2 3", the output is "2 + 3 = 5".

---

Something irreverent: Why using `TRUE` and `FALSE` when returning? To avoid magic numbers, you can use `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your input parameters start at `argv[1]`; `argv[0]` is always the string that you used to invoke the program.

Secondly `(int)*(argv[1])` doesn't convert `argv[1]` from a string to an integer; what it does is convert the character code of the first character in `argv[1]` from `char` to `int`.  Assuming ASCII, if argv[1] is `"10"`, then that line would convert the *character value* `'1'` (ASCII 49) from type `char` to type `int`.

You'll need to use a library function like `atoi` or `strtol` to convert your arguments from strings to integers, like so:

```
int a = (int) strtol( argv[1], NULL, 10 );
int b = (int) strtol( argv[2], NULL, 10 );
...
int answer = addition( a, b );
```

Read the [strtol man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) for an explanation of the parameters.