# confusion while understanding parameters of main

Tags: c, parameters, program-entry-point

while understanding the parameters of `main` function i.e, `int argc, char* argv[]`

i wrote a piece of code to understand these parameters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    printf("test\n");
    printf("%d %c",argc,*argv[argc-1]);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints

> test
>
> 1 F

here I don't understand why there is F as output. I mean how this is executed to result in output as F ?

I read about these perameters and main function at [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) and [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html). But still I don't understand how these works.

please explain .

EDIT: as mentioned in comments if I change the code to

```
printf("%d %s",argc,argv[argc-1]);
```

Now i'm getting the whole path of the file F:\file path

so does it mean `argv[0]` is the location of the file in drive?

Comment: What parameters did you supply when running your program? And did you happen to name your program something starting with F ?

Comment: after writing this program i just compiled and runned it.

Comment: I think you may want `printf("%d %s",argc,argv[argc-1]);`

Comment: @M.M I am running code::blocks and the program name is temp\main.c

Comment: argc is not 0, please read my que again. output of argc is 1.

Comment: @KenWhite Commonly, `argv[0]` is the name of the executable (often with full path), so it's probably not garbage. Perhaps the program is on `F:` drive.

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean will help

Comment: @M.M yeah the program is on F: drive . so it means argv[0] is always the drive name ?

Comment: @mssirvi to see what `argv[0]` is, make the code change suggested by Ed Heal

Comment: after changing the code suggested by Ed Heal, this prints the path of the file.

Comment: @M.M I updated the que. can you please help me?

Comment: It is the path of the executable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050961/is-argv0-name-of-executable-an-accepted-standard-or-just-a-common-conventi

Comment: ok I got it. thanxs @EdHeal

Answer (score 1):

It is not defined in the C standard, but on Unix argv[0] is the name of the executable. Then argv[1] the first argument, etc. I think that this is also true, most of the time, on Microsoft's Dos and their Windowing OSes.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words:
When you give your commandline the instruction to run your program, you can append some text, which can be accessed in your program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc,char*argv[])
{
    printf("This is the path or name of your programm: ");
    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);

    if(argc > 1) {
        printf("This is the first argument you gave your programm: ");
        printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    }

    if(argc > 2) {
        printf("This is the second argument you gave your programm: ");
        printf("%s\n", argv[2]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Try to run this example with:

```
<path_to_the_programm> Hallo Welt
```

You will see argc is an integer, which tells you how many arguments you gave the program. I hope it helped you.