# Why is argv[0] the applications name (at least by convention)?

Tags: language-agnostic, command-line-arguments, argv

I know you can theoretically pass anything you want to the application, so why include the applications name there, as it isn't even a safe way to check it?

It doesn't seem like there would be any use to it.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315812/why-does-argv-include-the-program-name

Comment: @tkausl thanks! I think that solves it ^^

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "argv\[0\] = name-of-executable" an accepted standard or just a common convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050961/is-argv0-name-of-executable-an-accepted-standard-or-just-a-common-conventi)

Answer (score 1):

It can be useful to find out how the program was called. You may have multiple symlinks to the same file, and argv[0] can be used to determine how the program was invoked.

Comment: But why would you need to do that? To have a "one that rules them all" application that is symlinked all over the place? Doesn't really seem to make sense.

Comment: Not only symlinks; also hard links.