# strlen(*argv) produces an unusual result

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, argv, argc

I ran the following just for fun, but cannot account for the result. Assume `./test WTF?` was run at the command line, and the output produced was 
`WTF? 6   2`.  Why is there such a vast discrepancy between the reported value of argc (2 - as expected) and strlen(*argv), which came up as 6. I know an array of strings isn't exactly what strlen is looking for, however, I thought the value it produced (if it produced anything) would be reasonably close to argc. Thoughts?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(argv[i]); j++)
        {
            printf("%c", argv[i][j]);

        }
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\t%lu\t%d", strlen(*argv), argc);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: The `WTF?` string is at `argv[1]`.

Comment: `argv[0]` is the program itself, in this case, `./test`. However, [you cannot rely on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050961/is-argv0-name-of-executable-an-accepted-standard-or-just-a-common-conventi).

Comment: `*argv` is `./test`, then 6 chars long.

Comment: argc is the count of strings in argv. argv[0] is the name of your program, in this case "./test" which has a length of 6.

Comment: `*argv` is `argv[0]`. Why do you expect any kind of connection between `argc` and `strlen(argv[0])`? These are two completely unrelated values.

Comment: "./test" looks like 6 characters to me.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing wrong here. The `argv` array contains two strings -

1. program name as invoked --> "./test"
2. "WTF?".

So in your example `strlen(argv[0])` will print 6 and `strlen(argv[1])` will print 4.

Comment: Correct and understood. What I did not realise I had done with strlen(*argv) was write a synonym for strlen(argv[0]). Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 3):

For example, if you run `gcc -o myprog myprog.c` in command line, you will get the followings:

```
argc
4 
argv[0]
   gcc 
argv[1]
   -o 
argv[2]
   myprog 
argv[3]
   myprog.c
```

Therefore, for your case you will get 6 (length of `./test` for `argv[0]`) instead of 4 (length of `WTF?` `argv[1]`) as you run `./test WTF?` in command line.