# sys.argv contains '-c', but not the script. Why?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I'm just curious about the `sys.argv` behavior I find strange and inconsistent.

I expected `sys.argv` to only contain the script arguments (not the arguments that are parsed by the `python3` executable).

In practice, I see that `sys.argv` contains the `-c` argument intended for `python3`. What surprises me then is that the next argument - the script body - is missing. I expect either 2 arguments or 4, but not 3.

What's the logic behind this?

```
$ python3 -c 'import sys;print(sys.argv)' 1 2
['-c', '1', '2']
```

**Update**:
Ok. I got it. This only happens with the `-c` argument and not other arguments:

```
$ python3 -b -c 'import sys;print(sys.argv)' -d 1 2
['-c', '-d', '1', '2']
```

I still find it confusing and with that in the inline script case the `argv[0]` would contain the script text or `-c <script text>` or `python3 -c <script text>`

**P.S.** Here is the script that initially confused me:

```
python3 -c '
import argparse
import sys
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
print(parser.parse_known_args(sys.argv))
' -a 1 -b 2 -c 3
(Namespace(), ['-c', '-a', '1', '-b', '2', '-c', '3'])
```

I was surprised to see the first -c in the output. Turns out you should not just pass `argv` to `parse_known_args`.

Comment: `argv[0]` is the name *of* the script. Everything else is an argument *to* the script. So, if you had both `-c` and the script text, then you couldn't use `argparse` normally, because the script text would be unexpected.

Comment: But `-c` is not an argument to a script. It's an argument to `python3`. `pythohn3` "consumes" the `-c` and the script text, so `-c` should not be in the arguments list.

Comment: You can find explanation here: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html

Comment: Yes, it's an argument to python3, but there still has to be *something* there in the argv array describing how the script was invoked (since there *is* no script filename that could be put there; if one put the text of the script in that position, poorly-written usage-error-handling code could end up making a user-confusion mess by printing that source code out to end users as if it were a command name). `-c` is a very reasonable choice; it's short and clear to the reader... and well, *some* choice had to be made, even if it was a decision to make `argv[0]` be `None`.

Comment: BTW, there's history for closing "why did the designers of language X choose to do Y?" questions as outside of the site's scope -- see [Is asking “why” on language specifications still considered as “primarily opinion-based” if it can have official answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio) on [meta].

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but closely related: [Is `argv[0]` = name-of-executable an accepted standard or just a common convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050961/is-argv0-name-of-executable-an-accepted-standard-or-just-a-common-conventi)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Something** has to be there (so programs that expect user-provided arguments to start at `argv[1]` still work correctly), and `-c` is as sensible a choice as any.

---

The logic is that there's only *one* special argv element, and that's the first one -- `argv[0]` -- used to identify how the script was invoked. Sometimes that's a name it was invoked under; in this case, `-c` tells you it was invoked by passing `python -c '...script text...'`.

All the other elements are expected to be arguments to the script itself. If the script text were there as an argument *to that script itself*, you couldn't use the same command-line parsing tools for scripts passed as text as you do for every other case.

---

As a point of comparison, look at `bash -c '...script text...' "$0" "$1"`, which tends to cause a fair bit of confusion (it's conventional to pass `_` in the `$0` position, but then people who see it are always asking "what's that placeholder for?"; it adds very little value). Python's approach of always using `-c` in the placeholder position and passing further arguments in position 1 and onwards makes sense.

Comment: Ok. I got it. This only happens with the `-c` argument and not other arguments:

   ` $ python3 -b -c 'import sys;print(sys.argv)' -d 1 2`
   ` ['-c', '-d', '1', '2']`

I still find it confusing and wish that in the inline script case the `argv[0]` would contain the script text or `-c <script text>` or `python3 -c <script text>`

Comment: >"-c is as sensible a choice as any." I find it a bit less sensible, because it's not *that* `-c` I've passed. It's an arbitrary inline script indicator that could as well be `"<inline-script>"` or `python3` or `python3 -c <script>` or `<script>` or `-c <script>`. Just not the plain `-c`

Comment: @Ark-kun: I think the key takeaway here is that you should almost always be ignoring `argv[0]`. It's never reliably *anything*. Don't expect it to be meaningful in this case, or indeed really in any case.

Comment: Yes. I was just confused by it being `-c`. My train of thought was as follows: "`argv[0]` == `-c` looks like an argument I've passed, not like a program name. That means that Python only has arguments in `argv`, not the program. But why does it include the `-c` arg that it has parsed?" I won't have been fooled if `argv[0]` contained anything other that `-c`.

Comment: `<inline-script>` would have been another reasonable choice, I agree.

Comment: I found my original source of confusion: It's `argparse`: calling `argparse.ArgumentParser().parse_known_args(sys.argv)` outputs the `-c` in its list of extra arguments. I.e. `(Namespace(), ['-c', '-a', '1', '-b', '2', '-c', '3'])` for `python3 -c <script> -a 1 -b 2 -c 3`. Turns out `parse_known_args` just does not expect `argv` to be passed in.