# Segmentation fault when file is not found even if I try to create it in C

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, fopen, argv

I'm writing a code that appends text to a file.
It uses `fopen` in the beginning of `WriteToFile` so even if the file does not exist, it creates it.

But, what happens when I enter no file at all? no arguments at all? Just `./a.out`?

Segmentation fault.

I don't know why, it seems to me I did everything fine to avoid any problems.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    
    char file_name[30] = "file.txt";
    
    printf("%s",file_name); /* for debugging : doesn't print it */
    
    if (0 != argc)
    {
        strcpy(file_name, argv[1]);
    }
    
    WriteToFile(file_name);
    
}
```

OR
(in case I can't really put a string literal into char array):

```
char file_name[30];
    
    if (0 == argc)
    {
       strcpy(file_name, "file.txt");
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(file_name, argv[1]);
    }
```

For both of the cases i'm getting

`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Comment: Even if you can't use a debugger, you can put a printf just before and just after the suspect line(s).  When run, if the before prints, but the after does not, your segfault lies between those prints; otherwise it is elsewhere.  Find the exact line of code before pondering why.

Comment: @Abel ,there is no greater debugger than `printf` :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```c
if (0 != argc)
```

The `argc` value is normally<sup>(a)</sup> the count of arguments *including* the program name. Hence, running `./a.out` will have an `argc` of one rather than zero. And, since `argv[argc]` is usually `NULL`, dereferencing it is not going to end well :-)

If you want to ensure another argument is available, you can use:

```c
if (argc > 1) {            // Have both argv[0] AND argv[1].
    nowSafeToUse(argv[1]);
}
```

In more detail, the C11 standard states:

> If they are declared, the parameters to the main function shall obey the following constraints:
>
> - The value of `argc` shall be nonnegative.
> - `argv[argc]` shall be a null pointer.
> - If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the array members `argv[0]` through `argv[argc-1]` inclusive shall contain pointers to strings, which are given implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup. The intent is to supply to the program information determined prior to program startup from elsewhere in the hosted environment. If the host environment is not capable of supplying strings with letters in both uppercase and lowercase, the implementation shall ensure that the strings are received in lowercase.
> - If the value of `argc` is greater than zero, the string pointed to by `argv[0]` represents the program name; `argv[0][0]` shall be the null character if the program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of `argc` is greater than one, the strings pointed to by `argv[1]` through `argv[argc-1]` represent the program parameters.
> - The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination.

---

As an aside regarding this line:

```c
printf("%s",file_name); /* for debugging : doesn't print it */
```

If this is not printing, it's probably because standard output is line buffered (default if it's determined to be an interactive device, otherwise fully buffered).

By not outputting a `\n` at the end, the characters are probably still sitting in a buffer somewhere, ready to be written. The crash will probably kill off the process without flushing the buffer. So a simple solution may be just to use one of:

```c
printf("%s",file_name);
puts(file_name);
```

---

As *another* aside, you're going to get into trouble if the filename you enter is larger than 29 characters since it will overflow `file_name`, allowing for the `\0` at the end as well.

A better approach may be just to use either your default string or `argv[1]` directly (without copying), something like:

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char *file_name = (argv > 1)
        ? argv[1]
        : "file.txt";
    printf("%s\n", file_name); // for debugging : probably does print it :-)
    
    WriteToFile(file_name);
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Not *required* by the standard since it allows for implementation-specific differences, but it's the usual case. Specifically, the phrase:

> ... which are given implementation-defined values by the host environment prior to program startup. The intent is to supply to the program information determined prior to program startup from elsewhere in the hosted environment.

pretty much means it can do whatever it wants :-)

A related answer (though a non-duplicate question) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050961/is-argv0-name-of-executable-an-accepted-standard-or-just-a-common-conventi/2051031#2051031).

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you very much. Is there any way to add "commands" to the `?` statment? I mean for example, to `printf("file.txt has been created because no file was entered")` in addition to the creation?

Comment: @Noob: you could do it in a *different* statement `printf("%s", (argc > 1) ? "" : "Used file.txt because you didn't specify a file\n");` but it's probably better to just turn the whole ternary expression into an `if` statement in that case, with multiple sub-statements in the `if` and `else` bits.

Answer (score 3):

When `argc` is 1, `argv` is treated as an array of 2 pointers to `char`. The first is a valid pointer (typically to the program name), the second is `NULL`.

`argv[1]` accesses the second element of `argv`. With no arguments supplied, `argc` will be 1 and `argv[1]` will be `NULL`. You're therefore dereferencing a `NULL` pointer.

The condition `0 != argc` should instead be `argc >= 2` or `argc > 1`, and the condition `0 == argc` should be `argc < 2` or `argc <= 1`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to account for the program's name so you should write `if (argc >= 2)` instead. See the [man](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html)

> The value of the argc argument is the number of command line arguments. The argv argument is a vector of C strings; its elements are the individual command line argument strings. **The file name of the program being run is also included in the vector as the first element; the value of argc counts this element.** A null pointer always follows the last element: argv[argc] is this null pointer.

argv[1] means index 1 but in C you start at index 0.

---

#### Fixed code

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    
    char file_name[30] = "file.txt";
    
    printf("%s",file_name); /* for debugging : doesn't print it */
    
    if (argc >= 2)
        strcpy(file_name, argv[1]);
    else
        return 1;  // exit program with error code.
    WriteToFile(file_name);
    return 0; // exit with success
}
```

Comment: Why would you `return 1` if there is not input of a file from the user? I want to create a default file in this case, called `"file.txt".`